# Aws Client does not resolve updated credentials in java sdk

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

In my application I am using AWS SQS client which is getting credentials via DefaultCredentialsProvider, which is using default profile from ~/.aws/credentials in following form:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = <<my-key-id>>
aws_secret_access_key = <<my-key>>
aws_session_token = <<my-token>>
```

Credentials are updated every 10 minutes and have 15 minute lifetime.
Application can start and use initial credentials correctly: sqs client is created and can send messages.
But after credentials file is updated - App does not see fresh credentials and throw Auth Error:

```
software.amazon.awssdk.services.sqs.model.SqsException: The security token included in the request is expired
```

SQS client is created in following way:

```
@Bean
public SqsAsyncClient sqsClient() {

    return SqsAsyncClient.builder()
            .credentialsProvider(
                    DefaultCredentialsProvider.builder()
                            .asyncCredentialUpdateEnabled(true)
                            .build())
            .build();
}
```

What is the correct way to use Credentials that will be changed dynamically?

AWS JAVA SDK BOM version 2.16.48 or 2.10.56 (same behavior)

Comment: Can't the java process itself handle the credentials and generate new ones instead of relying on some external process to do so?

Comment: These credentials are used by other processes except java app, so they need to be updated externally.

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution to this?